# TypeError: udf() missing 1 required positional argument: 'f'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I couldn't find any solution or question to my problem.

If I try to define a Spark-UDF Function (pyspark) e.g.:

```
@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def _return_an_integer(y):

    return y + random.randint(1, 99)

df = df.withColumn('randomInteger', _return_an_integer(col('1')))
```

I get the error message:

```
TypeError: udf() missing 1 required positional argument: 'f'
```

Has anybody a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Without annotation:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.UserDefinedPythonFunction. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.UserDefinedPythonFunction([class java.lang.String, class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction, class org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType$]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you try without an annotation? https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html

Comment: If I do so, I get another error message, see edited post

Comment: What version of Spark is this?

Comment: I may have found the issue: UDF can not handle nan-values in the df...

Comment: Possibly, but that's a runtime issue and your errors here are at compilation time

Comment: Regarding to this: [class java.lang.String, class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction, class org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType$])

is there some config or import which I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying lot of things, the problem was that my pyspark version didn't match the spark version.

Comment: Maybe clarify how that happened? Spark comes with pyspark binary, so did you use `pip install pyspark` separately?

Comment: As I am using a virtualenv, it could have happened.